# android studio AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I just get started with Android studio but I have ran into a problem 
in the beginning stage of setup. 
I have created my virtual device using AVD manager but whenever i hit 'run' button, it ask me to select device to run on but the drop box(Prefer android virtual device) doesnt show mine. what am i missing?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBCzE.png)

I have added link of the pictures. i apology for the inconvinience.  this site doesnt allow me to post pictures yet

Answer (score 0):

The **Nexus 4 API 27** is the virtual device that you have. If another device was successfully created, it would have been visible in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this **Image**

[image: Drop box options]

These options are used for operations that should be performed on your device **Nexus 4 API 27**

Your device is created and you can run your device using **Run** icon.

Answer (score 0):

When hit run button , in Available Virtual Device Section your Device is Shown. Just select and Click OK